# First Child não é selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código que gera um *slider* dinâmico, porém a propriedade *first-child* não funciona. Qual é o problema?

```
var elementoSlider = $('#dados-slider');
  var mostraImagem = "";
  var mostraDadosImagem = "";
 $('ul.slider li:first-child').addClass('slider-active');
  $.ajax({
    url: urlBase + "loja/slider",
    method: 'GET'
  }).done(function(retorno)
  {

    mostraImagem += "<ul id='sliders' class='slider'>";
    retorno.data.forEach(function(item)
    {
      mostraDadosImagem = "<li><img src='" + urlBase  + "imagem/slide/" + item.loja_slider_id + "/jpg' alt='Imagem Slider' title='Imagem Slider' class='imagem-slider' /><h1>Nome da Loja</h1></li>";
      mostraImagem += mostraDadosImagem;
    })

    mostraImagem += "</ul>";

    elementoSlider.html(mostraImagem);

  }).fail(function(data)
  {
    console.log("Erro de slider");
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você adiciona a classe na linha:

```
 $('ul.slider li:first-child').addClass('slider-active');
```

Mas logo em seguida, você executa o Ajax e reconstrói o html do Slider, substituindo assim o que você acabou de fazer:

```
elementoSlider.html(mostraImagem);
```

Sugiro a seguinte alteração:

```
var elementoSlider = $('#dados-slider');
  var mostraImagem = "";
  var mostraDadosImagem = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: urlBase + "loja/slider",
    method: 'GET'
  }).done(function(retorno)
  {

    mostraImagem += "<ul id='sliders' class='slider'>";
    retorno.data.forEach(function(item)
    {
      mostraDadosImagem = "<li><img src='" + urlBase  + "imagem/slide/" + item.loja_slider_id + "/jpg' alt='Imagem Slider' title='Imagem Slider' class='imagem-slider' /><h1>Nome da Loja</h1></li>";
      mostraImagem += mostraDadosImagem;
    })

    mostraImagem += "</ul>";

    elementoSlider.html(mostraImagem);
    $('ul.slider li:first-child').addClass('slider-active');

  }).fail(function(data)
  {
    console.log("Erro de slider");
  });      
});
```